# Call a (Rhino) JS function in Java and pass a variable in

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

after figuring out yesterday how to configure my Eclipse project to be able to run JS code (if your interested: [Build a JS server inside of Java for Google AppEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417958/)), I have the next question related to this topic: I got a JS file and a function within it. I need to run that function inside my Java code and to pass a (Java string) variable in it. My file is very basic, it currently looks like this:

```
public class Com_feedic_readabilityServlet extends HttpServlet {
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
   throws IOException {
  resp.setContentType("text/html"); 
  Context cx = ContextFactory.getGlobal().enterContext();
  cx.setOptimizationLevel(-1);
  cx.setLanguageVersion(Context.VERSION_1_5);
  Global global = Main.getGlobal();
  global.init(cx);
  Main.processSource(cx, "server_js/js_init.js");
 }
}
```

What I need to do now is calling the function `run()` within the `js_init.js`-file. How do I manage that?

Comment: Are you using the JDK 6 ScriptEngine mechanism?  Also, it's not at all clear what that function you posted has to do with, well, anything.

Comment: It just shows how I import the .js file. And I'm using an imported Rhino js.jar file, it's not exactly the ScriptEngine-mechanism (but I think it's based uppon it, besides: I got no clue).

Comment: Hmm ... well I read that blog post and it seemed unlike anything I've ever done with Rhino. I've always used the JDK ScriptEngine framework and the built-in (somewhat dated) version of Rhino, and that's very easy to use.

Comment: I'm not using the technique of that thing, just its basic structure (but I do use Java-files). A solution using ScriptEngine would be fine, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass the value of the parameter via a Binding object, as follows:

```
  package rhinodemo;

  import java.util.Date;
  import javax.script.*;

  public class RhinoDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
      ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

      Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
      bindings.put("currentTime", new Date());
      engine.eval(
         "function run(x) { println('x=' + x); }" +
         "run(currentTime);", bindings);
    }
  }
```

If you want your Java code to invoke a Javascript function called `run()` then create a script that (a) defines the `run()` function and (b) calls this function, passing a parameter to it. Then, in the Java side, you need to create a Bindings object and set the value of this parameter `bindings.put(currentTime, new Date())`.

Comment: I got the error "println not defined". How do I pass content evaluated by Rhino back to a variable (remember, I'm using a JS-server)?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
Object jsOut = Context.javaToJS(System.out, scope);
ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "out", jsOut);
```

and js file `out.println(<text>);`